# Same Query but two results?

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql query that lists count of title, artist

```
SELECT count(Key) AS Ocount, artist, title,domain, DATE_FORMAT(`FE`,'%m') AS eMonth
FROM gr 
WHERE domain = 'site.com'
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY eMonth,Ocount Desc
```

first results are

```
'195', 'akon', 'beautiful', 'site.com', '01'
'20', 'ludacris', 'intro', 'site.com', '01'
'11', 'don omar', 'taboo', 'site.com', '01'
```

running same query like

```
SELECT count(Key) AS Ocount, artist, title,domain, DATE_FORMAT(`FE`,'%m') AS eMonth
FROM gr 
WHERE domain = 'site.com'
AND artist = 'akon'
AND title = 'beautiful'
```

result

```
'100', 'akon', 'beautiful', 'site.com', '01'
```

how is this possible? Shouldnt it give the same results no matter how I am counting?

Comment: `count` is an aggregate function, so it works differently if you're grouping the data.

Comment: You're not using an aggregate correctly in the second example. Actually, either according to standards.

Comment: MySQL is lenient about the contents of the GROUP BY and will produce unexpected results if all SELECT cols are not represented there.

Comment: You are missing a `GROUP BY` on the second query which causes issues with the results.

Comment: but where are the extras coming from? if I have 10 apples....shouldnt count always be 10 if I'm grouping for apples?

Comment: so which result can i trust? the first or the second? and what changes should I be making to have the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the count of each title-artist combination, you'll want to use

```
GROUP BY artist, title
```

This will have `count(id)` represent the number of instances where the artist+title combination exists in that table.  You can use the `WHERE` clause to filter the results before `COUNT()` is calculated.

You can check to see if the results are accurate by starting with a small sample of data and checking if the results of `COUNT()` are accurate.

Grouping only by artist will result in a count of rows that match that artist regardless of title.

Comment: im still trying to make the two queries have the same results. How can I make the second query match the first or the other way?

Comment: If you want to see the total number of songs for a given artist, then use this: SELECT count(title), artist from gr group by artist.  Otherwise, can you be more specific about what results you want?  Maybe provide a sample of data and then a sample output that you want to see.